# C# Programatically Accessing a counter that is available only in 32-bit Performance Counter

Tags: c#, perfmon

I need to programatically access a performance counter of a 32-bit application that shows up only in the 32-bit PerfMon tool. It does not show up in the 64-bit PerfMon tool.

When I instantiate a PerformanceCounter of System.Diagnostics, it accesses only the counters registered to the 64-bit Performance Monitor.

How can I programmatically specify that I want to read the 32-bit performance counters on a machine and not the 64-bit counters?

Comment: I'm not sure there is anything you can do. However, in [Collecting 32-bit Performance Counters Using a 64-bit Operations Manager Agent](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/momteam/2012/05/24/collecting-32-bit-performance-counters-using-a-64-bit-operations-manager-agent/) a trick is suggested where the 32 bit counters are logged to a file using the 32 bit performance monitor. This file can then be read by a 64 bit process.